# Using ReCaptcha with jQuery Validate, giving correct response but gives error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, recaptcha

I'm using jQuery validate with a registration form for my website with a reCaptcha at the bottom. Here is the script to check the form for errors (edited to only the relevant parts):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkCaptcha", function() {
    var phpquery = $.ajax({url:"verify.php",
      type: "POST",
      async: false,
      data:{recaptcha_challenge_field:Recaptcha.get_challenge(),recaptcha_response_field:Recaptcha.get_response()},
      success:function(resp) {
        if (resp == 'false') {
          console.dir(resp);
          return false;
        } else {
          console.dir(resp);
          return true;
        }
      }
    });
  },"");

  $('#regForm').validate({
    rules:{
      recaptcha_response_field:{required:true,checkCaptcha:true}
    },
    messages:{
      recaptcha_response_field:{checkCaptcha:"Your Captcha response was incorrect. Please try again."}
    }
  });
});
```

What happens is when I enter the correct reCaptcha response and either click submit or tab out of the response text field, it will initially say `true` in the console, then immediately throw `false` and prevent me from submitting the form.

What also happens is when the incorrect reCaptcha response is entered, it will throw `false` like it's supposed to but for every letter I type in, it will submit that to `verify.php` and return `false`. When I finally get done typing in the correct reCaptcha, it doesn't recognize it as such and still returns `false`.

Reloading the reCaptcha also throws a `false`, even when the correct response is entered.

I know the `verify.php` works correctly, because when the `<form>` would have `action="verify.php,"` everything would work perfectly (i.e., tell you if you entered the correct reCaptcha, regardless of how many times you tried).

Am I missing something? Is there an easier, reliable way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, finally got it (although it just might be a work around). Here's the new `addMethod`:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkCaptcha", function() {
 var bfr = false;
 var phpquery = $.ajax({url:"verify.php",
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  data:{recaptcha_challenge_field:Recaptcha.get_challenge(),recaptcha_response_field:Recaptcha.get_response()},
  complete:function(resp) {
    if(resp.responseText.indexOf("false")>=0){
     Recaptcha.reload();
    }else{
     bfr = true;
    }
  }
 });
if(bfr){
   return true;
 }
},"");
```

I also added `onkeyup:false`, `onclick:false`, and `onfocusout:false` to `validate()`.
This seems to get the job done.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `onkeyup: false` option inside `.validate()`.

Otherwise, every single time you type one letter, it will run your `checkCaptcha` method and send an incomplete Captcha code to the server.  I believe once an incorrect Captcha code is sent, it's now expired and you can't send the same code again.

Either way, I think it's best not to send a code to the server until after the field is complete.

```
$('#regForm').validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    rules:{
        recaptcha_response_field: {
            required: true,
            checkCaptcha: true
        }
    },
    messages:{
        recaptcha_response_field: {
            checkCaptcha: "Your Captcha response was incorrect. Please try again."
        }
    }
});
```

Also, if the Captcha fails, you'll need to trigger a refresh to get a new code.

```
Recaptcha.reload();
```

Inside your `success` callback, perhaps...

```
success:function(resp) {
    if (resp == 'false') {
        console.dir(resp);
        Recaptcha.reload();  // get a new captcha code on failure
        return false;
    } else {
        console.dir(resp);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: So this resolves the issue of sending the response for every keystroke, but I'm still having the issue where `verify.php` will initially give me `true` then go straight to `false`, preventing the page from submitting.

Comment: @synthrom, yeah, even though we disabled the `onkeyup` event, the rule is still being evaluated on every blur and then again when submit is clicked.  You can not keep sending the same code to the server.  Somehow you need to check once and disable the method as soon as the code is correct.

Comment: I've added `onlick:false` and `onfocusout:false` to `validate()`, so that seems to take care of those issues. The `addMethod` is returning `true` but it is still throwing the error message `"Your Captcha response was incorrect. Please try again."` and I can't figure out why...

Comment: I'm not in a place where I can help much yet.  Meanwhile, investigate using the `remote` method instead of your custom.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your first addMethod validator is about how you return true or false, and the second is more complex than what it should be. I don't know how you treat the thing from server-side but maybe this code is what you need:

> http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/06/03/adding-recaptcha-validator-to-jquery-validate/

That works great for me!

Answer (score -1):

Here is my idea specially regarding '***validating captcha using AJAX request***'.

the main reason for adding a captcha in a form is for a verification whether it is a bot or human who did the form submission. so even if other fields have errors, after a successful captcha submission obviously we know it is human. So, It is totally fine to remove the captcha field after its first success (please do refresh the captcha until it is a success). Then can handle other fields as usualy.

Any objections ?